# Java Heap Space Error - Combining Multiple Excel Files Into One Workbook (with multiple sheets)

Tags: java, excel, memory, apache-poi, heap-memory

I'm attempting to use a Java program to combine 25 individual Excel files into one Excel workbook with 25 sheets. I can easily just copy/paste the sheets, but I wanted to solve it with code. My code below works with 24 of the 25 sheets; however, my largest sheet has 760,000 rows of data (the rest only have around 1000), and whenever I run the program, it cuts off because of a Java Heap Space error.

I read that a possible solution is to simply increase the heap space, but this isn't good practice. How do I make my program use up less memory on the heap?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelCombiner {
    private FileList fileList = new FileList();
    private Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    public void createWorkbook() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("MIMIC_DATABASE.xlsx"));
        createSheets();
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        workbook.close();
    }

    public void createSheets() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        for (File file : fileList.getFiles()) {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
            Workbook fileBook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            String sheetName = file.getName().replace(".xlsx", "");
            //New Sheet in Workbook that we're copying info into
            Sheet newSheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);
            //Old Sheet, fileBook should just be an excel file with one sheet
            Sheet oldSheet = fileBook.getSheetAt(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < oldSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                Row row = oldSheet.getRow(i);
                Row newRow = newSheet.createRow(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
                    Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
                    Cell newCell = newRow.createCell(j);

                    //Make sure to convert all old cells into String/Text
                    //Then copy them over to newCell
                    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
                    String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                    newCell.setCellValue(cellValue);
                }
            }
            fileBook.close();
        }
        //workbook.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        ExcelCombiner excelCombiner = new ExcelCombiner();
        excelCombiner.createWorkbook();
    }
}
```

Comment: *but this isn't good practice.* - sometimes it is, that is why you can do it.  For example in JDK1.8 the value is *maximum heap size
Smaller of 1/4th of the physical memory or 1GB.*

Comment: Also you maybe have more luck with the streaming version https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/package-summary.html

Comment: Whether `SXSSF` will help depends on where exactly the heap space error occurs. `SXSSF` is for write only and so only can be used for creating the resulting `Workbook workbook`. But if the error occurs while creating `Workbook fileBook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);`, then this will not help. Then only a combination of  `SXSSF` for writing the resulting `Workbook workbook` and a [Excel Streaming Reader](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader) for reading the `Workbook fileBook ` will possibly help.

Comment: The error appears to occur just in the process of iterating through the cells of the rows of my extremely large excel file. It always appears 30 seconds after printing "CHARTEVENTS.xlsx". I'm going to try the SXSSF first and report back to y'all. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter, it turns out the error does occur while writing Workbook fileBook = new XSSFWorkbook(file). How would I use Excel Streaming Reader to help read the file?

Comment: Please follow the link I gave in my comment. There are examples given for how to use. If you have concrete problems or questions, please edit your question about the concrete problems you have using the streaming reader.